# OpenVPN send an email notification when a client connect

Tags: windows-10, openvpn, shell-script

I would like to get an email notification when a client connect/disconnect to/from my OpenVPN server which is running on a Windows 10 machine. I want to include client's common_name, date and time, remote_ip, local_ip as email content.

I have seen some email scripts written for *nix environments ([Example 1](https://www.snbforums.com/threads/tutorial-openvpn-connection-disconnection-email-notifications.20828/), [Example 2](https://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/openvpn-connection-email-notifications.36633/)) but I was unable to get them running for OpenVPN Windows.

I appreciate if someone can suggest me a proper script for this matter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the
[Reference manual for OpenVPN 2.4](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/)
the parameters for `–client-connect` and `–client-disconnect`.

I believe that on Windows you will need to use `.bat` scripts as arguments.

The following example is nothing more than a guess, but it will be easy
for you to find more details by experimenting:

- *--client-connect connect.bat*

  ```
  del %common_name%.disconnect
  echo CONNECT %date% %time% > %common_name%.connect
  ```
- *--client-disconnect disconnect.bat*

  ```
  del %common_name%.connect
  echo DISCONNECT %date% %time% > %common_name%.disconnect
  ```